# Recursively delete all occurences of an element in a singly linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am leaning data structures and algorithms using C, but I can't figure out how to recursively solve this problem.

It has simple iterative solution, but I need some help for the recursive version.

Here's my recursive version:

```
void delAllOcc(node** headRef,int key) {
    node * prev;
    if (*headRef != NULL && (*headRef)->data == key) {
        prev = *headRef;
        *headRef = (*headRef)->next;
        free(prev);
    }
    else {
        if (*headRef != NULL) {
            delAllOcc(&(*headRef)->next,key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that recursion for this problem is a very bad idea because it's less efficient and you might get a stack overflow for very long lists

Comment: That code is _recursive_ not _iterative_ - you state that it is your _iterative_ version. As it happens your honest attempt at a recursive solution is far more useful to anyone answering, your working iterative solution would be of little relevance.  Recursion is a "neat trick" beloved of computer science courses - in the real world it is best avoided because real computers have finite stacks.  In this case your list length could easily exceed maximum call stack depth.  Learn it, pass your course, then know to use with caution and certainly not in unconstrained situations such as this.

Comment: yea i should've mentioned that it's my recursive attempt , I written it wrong , my bad. Thanks for your explanation really appreciate it .

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not call itself when it is deleting a node.

Look at this code snippet

```
if (*headRef != NULL && (*headRef)->data == key) {
    prev = *headRef;
    *headRef = (*headRef)->next;
    free(prev);
}
```

there is no recursive call of the function itself.

The function can look the following way

```
void delAllOcc( node **headRef, int key ) 
{
    if ( *headRef != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *headRef )->data == key )
        {
            node *tmp = *headRef;
            *headRef = ( *headRef )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            headRef = &( *headRef )->next;
        }

        delAllOcc( headRef, key );
    }
}
```

To get an iterative solution just substitute the if statement for a while statement and remove the recursive call.

```
void delAllOcc( node **headRef, int key ) 
{
    while( *headRef != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *headRef )->data == key )
        {
            node *tmp = *headRef;
            *headRef = ( *headRef )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            headRef = &( *headRef )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution . The above was my recursive version and not the iterative one . Sorry I've written it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The *cleanest* recursive solution doesn't use tail-recursion, unfortunately:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
        struct node *next;
        int key;
        };

struct node *del_recursive (struct node *ptr, int key)
{
if (!ptr) return ptr;

ptr->next = del_recursive(ptr->next, key);
if (ptr->key == key) {
        struct node *del = ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        free(del);
        }
return ptr;
}
```

---

This version *does* use tail-recursion, but gcc -O3 doesn't seem to eat it:

---

```
struct node *del_recursive_tail (struct node *ptr, int key)
{
if (!ptr) return ptr;

if (ptr->key == key) {
        struct node *del = ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        free(del);
        }
if (!ptr) return ptr;
ptr->next = del_recursive_tail(ptr->next, key);
return ptr;
}
```

---

Note: I replaced the pointer-to-pointer argument with a plain pointer, and changed the return type to a pointer. Otherwise, recursion would make little sense.

Comment: Thanks , your solution is really helpful . I should've mentioned that it's recursive and not iterative .

Comment: @wildplasser For starters this statement " I replaced the pointer-to-pointer argument with a plain pointer, and changed the return type to a pointer. Otherwise, recursion would make little sense." does not make a sense. Secondly the presented by you code has a bug.

Comment: @RoyLy : it **is** recursive. There are no loops.

Comment: yours is recursive and mine also , but above my code I stated that this is an iterative version , it was by mistake. @wildplasser